# When reading from PROGMEM using pointers it skips one character

Tags: arduino

i am trying to understand what is going on.
I have a text saved on PROGMEM, then i want to iterate over it using pointers.
using pgm_read_byte function.
But when i print the output it skips one character.
What i am doing wrong?

```
#include <Arduino.h>

const char dummyText[] PROGMEM = {"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println(F("initializing"));
  const char *ptr = (const char *) dummyText;
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Serial.print("Char: ");
    Serial.println((char) pgm_read_byte(ptr + i));
    ptr++;
  }

}

void loop() {}
```

I got the following output:

```
Serial port COM10 opened
initializing
Char: L
Char: r
Char: m
Char: i
Char: s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading every other character because the result of ptr+i inside your loop is ptr, ptr+2, ptr+4. This is because you are incrementing both ptr and i inside the loop.

Suggestion: remove `ptr++;`